# Why can't laravel/eloquent find certain table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch some data from a table called "category", but laravel is throwing the

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found" error.

I've tried with other table names like **"company"** and it works perfectly. Both of these tables exist but one of them can not be found with the same code.

This throws the error:

```php
public static function getCategories()
    {
        $categories = [];

        $cat = DB::table('category')->get();
        if (isset($cat)){
            foreach ($cat as $category_name){
                array_push($categories, $category_name);
            }
            return json_encode($categories);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This works as expected (same code except for the table name string):

```php
public static function getCategories()
    {
        $categories = [];

        $cat = DB::table('company')->get(); //table name changed
        if (isset($cat)){
            foreach ($cat as $category_name){
                array_push($categories, $category_name);
            }
            return json_encode($categories);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The only difference between those two tables is table collation:
company: utf8_general_ci
category: utf8mb4_swedish_ci

Comment: check your table name

Comment: hit composer dump-autoload

Comment: Please show your Category Model code

Comment: Both tables do exist in the database: [picture](https://imgur.com/a/MDP8feH)
@AkashKumarVerma

Comment: I'm not using a model for either of these table, just searching straight from the DB with the table name @LimKeanPhang

Comment: You should create a model and insert place protected $table = 'category'; this way you should able to run your query. My guess is you've table name similar using category

Comment: 'composer dump-autoload' had no effect for me. @AkashKumarVerma

Comment: can you show me complete error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out we had two separate database-servers with *almost* identical data in them. Both had databases and tables with the same names, but one was missing the category table. 
Of course I was connected to the wrong server from laravel after all.

TL;DR: Simple user error in configuration.

Comment: Thats why i tell u to check the connection in the comments earlier. Guess i am right? U skipped me 

Comment: Yeah, I had wrong information about the server. To me the configuration looked fine and it was correctly configured to connect to the server I *thought* to be the correct one. Both of us were right, nice tips!

Answer (score 0):

Create a model if it you don't have one. Add the following into your category model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category';
}
```

Controller

```
public static function getCategories()
{
    $categories = [];

    $cat = Category::all();
    if (isset($cat)){
        foreach ($cat as $category_name){
            array_push($categories, $category_name);
        }
        return json_encode($categories);
    }
    return null;
}
```

You're currently using Query Builder, try use eloquent way.

Comment: Has no effect for me, I get the same error. the error message is telling me it's searching for the correct table from the correct database. [picture](https://imgur.com/a/OxADI60)

Full error message:
"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXXX.category' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `category`) "
XXXX is the database name, no typo's or anything here, other tables are found from the same database.

When I run the sql command (select * from `category`) against the database it returns the data correctly

Comment: Hmmm..Try the updated answer's approach. Check your env for database connection as well.

Comment: php artisan config:clear , php artisan cache:clear , php artisan view:clear

Comment: "php artisan config:clear , php artisan cache:clear , php artisan view:clear" had no effect for me, I still get the same error.

Comment: Yep, I now have  
`public static function getCategories()
    {  
        $categories = [];  

        $cat = Category::all();  
        if (isset($cat)){  
            foreach ($cat as $category_name){  
                array_push($categories, $category_name);  
            }  
            return json_encode($categories);  
        }  
        return null;  
    }`  
and the category model:  
`<?php  
namespace App;  

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category';
}`
@LimKeanPhang

Comment: Yes, still the same error: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXXX.category' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `category`)"

Comment: Did you add App/Model/Category? on top

Comment: Did you rename or changed sometime in migration file? :O .That's odd for this error..

Comment: Hmm, I don't think anything there is helpful. I'm not using drupal and I can find the category table with mysql workbench, pure sql pdo request from elsewhere... @LimKeanPhang

Comment: Check your migration file for category and see if something went wrong inside..That's the last troubleshooting that i can thought of.

Comment: The database was created before I started this project and I haven't touched the structure at all, only added some data to other tables. So I'm not using laravel migrations.